# Cache: Como utilizar mod_headers

Tags: apache, htaccess, servidor, nginx, cache

Tenho um servidor **Nginx** num ambiente compartilhado onde não é possível habilitar o `max-age` pois o mesmo faz parte do `mod_expires`, no qual só é disponível em ambiente dedicado.

Fui instruído pelo suporte a utilizar o `mod_headers`, mas já dei uma pesquisa na net e vi o site do Apache mas não consegui fazer.

Tentei colocar no `.htaccess` do `/` e do `/www` mas não teve jeito. Coisas que eu já tentei:

```
<FilesMatch "(?i)^.*\.(ico|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css)$">
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A2592000
</FilesMatch>
```

```
<FilesMatch ".(flv|swf|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css|txt|eot|woff|ttf|svg|JPG)$">  
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"  
</FilesMatch>
```

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/gif       86400000
ExpiresByType image/png       86400000
ExpiresByType image/jpg       86400000
```

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf|css|js)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Alguém me pode ajudar a usar o `mod_headers`?